Sum of roots is an integer
Let $f = X^3 + aX + b \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ with roots $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{C}$.  Show that if $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x_1^n + x_2^n +x_3^n\in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
I tried to solve it like this :
We observe that  $P_n(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^n+ x_2^n +x_3^n \in \mathbb{Z} [x_1,x_2,x_3]$ is symmetric polynomial.
By fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials $\exists Q_n \in \mathbb{Z} [x_1,x_2,x_3]$ such that $Q_n(s_1,s_2,s_3)=P_n$ where $s_1=x_1+x_2+x_3, s_2=x_1x_2+x_3x_2+x_2x_3, s_3=x_1x_2x_3$
Because $s_1=0, s_2=a, s_3=-b$ (by Vieta's formulas) we have that $P_n= Q_n(s_1,s_2,s_3) \in \mathbb{Z}. \blacksquare$
Is this correct? If not , can someone please give me an idea?

It is correct. All symmetric polynomial expressions of the roots are integers.
